# Wagtail import needs publish() to display images

Tags: django, wagtail

During a data migration to Wagtail, images are being created and added to the article body.

As eg.

```
<embed alt="Paralympics. Demotix/Julio Etchart. All rights reserved." embedtype="image" format="fullwidth" id="2453"/>
```

and are visible in the admin screen but not on the live article. If I click the `Publish` option in the admin screen, the images then become visible on the live article (along with a publish success message even though it was already live).

I would like to run whatever process is run by the Publish button during the article migration (so that images are visible on site), but I can't work out what functions it is running.

I have tried a variety of options in the shell to see what might work including:

```
Article.save()
```

and (just in case fetching and publishing a revision does the trick):

```
a = Article.get_revision()
a.publish()
```

Neither of those seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Which models are you updating in your data migration? `PageRevision`, the page model, or both?

Comment: @gasman It's a model called `LegacyContentPage` which subclasses `Page`. We are not explicitly using `PageRevision`, that was just something I tried in the shell to see if I could reproduce the effect of clicking `Publish` in the admin page. (I'll edit question to clarify that).

Comment: If you're writing your changes to the page model, that should definitely take effect immediately on the live page, because that's where the live serve view takes its page data from (not from PageRevision records or anything else). The only possibility I can think of is that your site is behind a server-side cache, and the publish action is clearing the cache (e.g. because you're using http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2.1/reference/contrib/frontendcache.html). Does that sound plausible?

Comment: No, caching is not the problem – this problem occurs in local development with no such caching. Also, the problem arises even with freshly migrated content which has not been viewed yet.